# How do i publish an iOS app?

Tags: iphone

i am try to submit my app into itune store. But when i sigin ituneconnect and choose "Manage Your Applications". i got following:
"An updated version of the iOS Developer Program Agreement is available and requires your acceptance. To restore your ability to create new applications and upload binaries, the Agent of your development team must log in to the Developer Member Center to review and accept this agreement."

Please help me with the problem! Thanks so so much!!!

Comment: Did you `log in to the Developer Member Center to review and accept this agreement.`?

Comment: I logged into the Developer Member Center but found nothing to review and accept agreement :(. please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Login into developer.apple.com/ios, you should see a yellow notice on the top of the page, follow the link and accept the new ToC for the Developer Program

Comment: :( I logged into it but found nothing on the top of the page. please help me a more specific. Thanks you,andreamazz!!